Flutter: widget.index issue, will not +1
I'm looking for a little help, I can't find a solution anywhere.
I have a Hive DB of 70 'cards' each card has 20 entries.
IE Lable1, Lable2, Lable 3....
GPSLon1, GPSLon2, GPSLon 3....
GPSLat1, GPSLat2, GPSLat 3....
I have a class that puts the card together, displays it and moves to the next.
I am trying to put 'Distance to the Next Section (card) on each card
So GPSLon1,GPSLat1 to GPSLon2,GPSLat 2
When the class is called 'Widget.index' replaces the number (ie GPSLon${widget.index}).
I need to call the NEXT GPS, IE GPSLon${widget.index +1} so I can calculate the distance.
But it will not add the 1. I just get the default 0.00.
Thank for any help.
My Code :-
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher_string.dart';
import 'package:map_launcher/map_launcher.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:rallybuddy2/admin/section_editor.dart';
import 'package:rallybuddy2/functions/globals.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';

class BuildEditableSectionCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const BuildEditableSectionCard(this.index, {super.key});

  final int index;

  @override
  State<BuildEditableSectionCard> createState() =>
      _BuildEditableSectionCardState();
}

class _BuildEditableSectionCardState extends State<BuildEditableSectionCard> {
  final routeSelection = Hive.box('routeSelection');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final labelText =
        routeSelection.get('LabelText${widget.index}', defaultValue: '-');
    final textTop =
        routeSelection.get('TextTop${widget.index}', defaultValue: '-');
    final textMiddle =
        routeSelection.get('TextMiddle${widget.index}', defaultValue: '-');
    final textBottom =
        routeSelection.get('TextBottom${widget.index}', defaultValue: '-');
final timeFrom =
    routeSelection.get('TimeFrom${widget.index}', defaultValue: '-');
final timeTo =
    routeSelection.get('TimeTo${widget.index}', defaultValue: '-');
final w3wText =
    routeSelection.get('W3WText${widget.index}', defaultValue: '-');

    final double lat1 = routeSelection.get('GPSLatitude${widget.index}', defaultValue:        0.00);
    final double lon1 = routeSelection.get('GPSLongitude${widget.index}', defaultValue: 0.00);



 final double lat2 = routeSelection.get('GPSLatitude${widget.index + 1}',defaultValue: 0.00);
 final double lon2 = routeSelection.get('GPSLongitude${widget.index + 1}',defaultValue: 0.00);

print('Lat 1 = $lat1');
print('Log 1 = $lon1');
print('Lat 2 = $lat2');
print('Lon 2 = $lon2');
print('Index = $widget.index');

final Distance distance = Distance();
final double calculatedDistance = distance.as(
  LengthUnit.Mile,
  LatLng(lat1, lon1),
  LatLng(lat2, lon2),
);

return Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Color(routeSelection.get('BackgroundColor${widget.index}',
        defaultValue: Colors.white.value)),
    border: Border.all(
      color: Color(routeSelection.get('BorderColor${widget.index}',
          defaultValue: Colors.black.value)),
      width: 5, // border color
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
  ),
  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 5),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      // Label Text
      if (labelText != '-')
        Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              labelText,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: routeSelection.get('LabelFontSize${widget.index}',
                    defaultValue: 16.0),
                color: Color(routeSelection.get('LabelColor${widget.index}',
                    defaultValue: Colors.black.value)),
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
          ],
        ),

      // Top Text
      if (textTop != '-')
        Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              textTop,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: routeSelection.get('TextFontSize${widget.index}',
                    defaultValue: 16.0),
                color: Color(routeSelection.get('TextColor${widget.index}',
                    defaultValue: Colors.black.value)),
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
          ],
        ),

      // Times From and To
      if (timeFrom != '-' || timeTo != '-')
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            if (timeFrom != '-')
              Text(
                timeFrom,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: routeSelection.get(
                      'TimeFontSize${widget.index}',
                      defaultValue: 16.0),
                  color: Color(routeSelection.get(
                      'TimeColor${widget.index}',
                      defaultValue: Colors.black.value)),
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            if (timeTo != '-')
              Text(
                ' - $timeTo',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: routeSelection.get(
                      'TimeFontSize${widget.index}',
                      defaultValue: 16.0),
                  color: Color(routeSelection.get(
                      'TimeColor${widget.index}',
                      defaultValue: Colors.black.value)),
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
          ],
        ),

      // Middle Text
      if (textMiddle != '-')
        Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(
              textMiddle,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: routeSelection.get('TextFontSize${widget.index}',
                    defaultValue: 16.0),
                color: Color(routeSelection.get('TextColor${widget.index}',
                    defaultValue: Colors.black.value)),
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ],
        ),

      // GPS Link
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          _launchMapsUrl(
            routeSelection.get('GPSLatitude${widget.index}',
                defaultValue: 0.0),
            routeSelection.get('GPSLongitude${widget.index}',
                defaultValue: 0.0),
          );
        },
        child: Text(
          'Open Google Maps',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: routeSelection.get('GPSFontSize${widget.index}',
                defaultValue: 16.0),
            color: Color(routeSelection.get('GPSColor${widget.index}',
                defaultValue: Colors.blue.value)),
          ),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),

      // W3W Link
      if (w3wText != '-')
        Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                _launchW3W(w3wText);
              },
              child: Text(
                'Open What 3 Words',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: routeSelection.get('W3WFontSize${widget.index}',
                      defaultValue: 16.0),
                  color: Color(routeSelection.get('GPSColor${widget.index}',
                      defaultValue: Colors.blue.value)),
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),

      // Bottom Text
      if (textBottom != '-')
        Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(
              textBottom,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: routeSelection.get('TextSize${widget.index}',
                    defaultValue: 16.0),
                color: Color(routeSelection.get('TextColor${widget.index}',
                    defaultValue: Colors.black.value)),
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 25),
          ],
        ),
      Column(
        children: [
          Text('Distance to next Section $calculatedDistance'),
        ],
      ),
      // Edit Button
      MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => SectionEditor(widget.index),
            ),
          );
        },
        color: Colors.blue[200],
        child: const Text('Edit this Section'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
    );
  }

  // Launch URL for Maps
  void _launchMapsUrl(double lat, double lon) async {
    final availableMaps = await MapLauncher.installedMaps;
    await availableMaps.first
        .showMarker(coords: Coords(lat, lon), title: "Rally Buddy");
  }

  // Launch URL for What3Words
  void _launchW3W(String w3wwords) async {
    final url = 'https://what3words.com/$w3wwords';
    if (!await launchUrlString(url)) throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}

